# Accesing files from shared in google drive

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

Im using drive api sample code for accessing google drive files in my app.But i cannot access the files that were shared with me.Do i need to change scope of google drive api in ios to access all files shared with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of the files shared with you, you can use the `drive.files.list` [request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) with the `sharedWithMe` [filter](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters).