# python google drive api. Download files in a drive shared with me

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

Following the tutorial, I'm able to list the files (and download them) in a given directory of my google drive.

The key part is

```
pageToken = ""
dir_id = <google drive directory id>
while pageToken is not None:
   query = "'" + dir_id + "' in parents"
   fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)"
   task = self.drive.files().list(q=query,
                       pageSize=1000,
                       pageToken=pageToken,
                       fields=fields)
   response = task.execute()
   pageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')
```

When `dir_id` is the id of one of **mine** directories, this works.

But when I set `dir_id` to a directory from another drive **shared with me**, the query always returns an empty list.
It does not raise "permission denied".

QUESTION: How do I list directories/download files from a directory inside a drive shared with me ?

This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991357/accesing-files-from-shared-in-google-drive), but I do not understand the answer.

EDIT: Someone else has a google drive, and shared that drive with me. I want to download from there. Thus I not not download from my drive. Instead I download from the other user's drive.

EDIT: change the title which was misleading.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `a drive shared with me`, I cannot understand this. In this case, do you want to retrieve the file list from the shared drive? Or, do you want to retrieve the file list from a shared folder in another user's Google Drive?

Comment: @Tanaike The second possibility. I added an "Edit" to make is more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425131/5371582)

```
dir_id = "1...z"  # directory I want to list
items = []
while pageToken is not None:
   query = "'" + dir_id + "' in parents"
   fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)"
   task = service.files().list(q=query, pageSize=1000,
                                    supportsAllDrives=True,
                                    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                    spaces='drive',
                                    pageToken=pageToken,
                                    fields=fields)
   response = task.execute()
   items.extend(response['files'])
   pageToken = response.get("nextPageToken")
for item in items:
   print(item["name"])
```

The secret was `supportsAllDrives=Trure` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True`.

Comment: I guess the `service` instance is created by `googleapiclient.discovery` `build()` call. What credentials do you supply for that? Is that your account google credentials or the target account ( the one shared files with you). I need to download selected files by their names, from shared drive folder that actually do not need any permission, as this drive folder is shared with anyone